# Get data form by ajax in server asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I try to send a form by Ajax to the server side of an another page, save it, and stay in the same page.

Ajax code:

```
function SaveJS() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://' + $('#ip').val() + 'EditSochen.aspx?id=3',
        data: $('#form1').serialize(),
        success: function () {
            $('#div2').css("display", "none")
        }
    });
}
```

Server code in 'http://' + $('#ip').val() + 'EditSochen.aspx?id=3' page:

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Response.Clear();            //clears the existing HTML
            Response.ContentType = "text/plain";  //change content type
            Response.Write("fgf");    //writes out the new name
            Response.End();             //end
        }
```

It arrives to the server-side of the another page but returns the other page instead of stay in the same page, why?

Thanks,

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using a ASHX file for this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem - I need to `return false` from the `SaveJS()` func.

**Code:**

```
function SaveJS() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://' + $('#ip').val() + 'EditSochen.aspx?id=3',
        data: $('#form1').serialize(),
        success: function () {
            $('#div2').css("display", "none")
        }
    });
return false;
}
```